# Store jQuery plugin object in element data attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

what do you think about storing object of jQuery plugin in elements data attribute?

For example, something like this:

```
function MyPlugin(element, config) {

   function init() {
     $(element).data('myPlugin', this);
   }

}
```

And then I can access it like this: `$('someSelector').data('myPlugin')`

How this way of storing object influence performance, memory etc? 
Do you have any better way, how to achieve accessing elements plugin instance?

Thank you very much for your opinions.